# Using a Blender textured 3d model in PowerPoint

Tags: export

I have created a 3D model and added texture to it in Blended.

How do I save the file in a way that it keeps the texture so I can use it in PowerPoint 365.

Seem to always lose the colour and end up with just the model shape.

Thanks,

Comment: Wait, what? Powerpoint can import .blend files? That's new...

Comment: Did you follow [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3KbBDrKM_n4)? It shows how to do it, but, alas, the monkey is not textured. Try to pack texture into your .blend file using UVs and then export the object. You may also set PP as your external app.

Comment: Not .blend but LibreOffice accepts e.g. Collada.

Comment: Did you test this? Why would packing change the result of an export?

Comment: I didn't, hence the word "try". Not change the result but  give the desired effect that's object imported with textures.

Comment: No, you can add 3D models to PowerPoint 365. I would like to be able to build models in Blender, and then export them in a format that can be imported into PowerPoint. Every time I try I lose the texture. I am looking for a way to export textured models from Blender.

Comment: I can't find an export file type that keeps the texture that I have added in Blender.

Comment: obj file format should work

Comment: @lemon Yes, this seems to be working, indeed. Thanks for your comment. :)

Answer (score 7):

Export GLB file with it's textures and import it to PowerPoint.

how to set up the glb textures properly is shown here:
https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html

Edit:
This is the setup for the textures
[image]

and then import from file
[image]

Comment: Hi ! Thanks for your answer. Could you maybe add some screenshots of the steps that you did to make it work ? I think that would be very helpful. Thanks,

Comment: Here's a video of glTF models being used in Powerpoint:  https://youtu.be/eslA0OGgQ58?t=1810

Comment: @emackey Thanks for the video !

Comment: @emackey Thanks for the additional screen shots ! :)